# Is it klout api uncompleted yet? Having issus get data through it

Tags: php, api, authentication, klout

Hi I wanna use klout api to get user's score of facebook or twitter. But I could not make a app like what I did when I am using facebook or twitter api. I have two keys: one is oauth key and one is partner key, what's the difference?? How do I make calls using klout apis? I tried [here](http://klout.com/s/developers/v2), but still could not make successfully calls, or even add a login button in my page, could someone help me and give me some sample code please, thanks!

Comment: What's the code you've tried so far?

Comment: @emie http://klout.com/s/developers/v2 and http://klout.com/s/developers/oauth, I tried both these two pages samples

Comment: Neither of those documentation pages show any PHP.  It sounds as if you want to use the API V2, not the oauth.  Have you tried writing any code to access the documented items?  It looks like you should be able to use either `file_get_contents()`, curl, or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Have you registered for an account and received API keys? A few points:

- The OAuth API is moderated. Keys generated for it are not activated until approved. You would not be able to add a login button to your page until applying and being approved for a key.
- The V2 API is more open, but still requires you to register at http://developer.klout.com/member/register
- You cannot currently lookup Facebook users on the API due to Facebook's Platform Terms of Service.
- The samples on the pages are generally incomplete in that they require you to include the key, have an active application profile, and have the callback URL set on that application profile.